# MySQL - Select rows with multiple occurrence of LIKE within a field

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have this table:

**id**    **post_content**

1. Lorem ipsum Mike dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.
2. Lorem ipsum Mike dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing Mike elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.
3. Lorem ipsum Mike dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing Mike elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore Mike.

How can I construct a SELECT ..... post_content LIKE %Mike% query that will only return rows with multiple occurrences of Mike? In this case, record 2 and 3.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like you have most of what you need in the last sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe if you tried:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE post_content LIKE '%Mike%Mike%'
```

This is tricky and I don't have MySQL right now to try it. I know from past experience that Oracle and MS SQL worked differently with that same approach, so you'll have to try it.

Comment: Oracle and MySQL (and any other database) should behave the same way.

Comment: this method and replace would both have 1 flaw which is if mike is in the middle of a word.  probably not a big deal for mike but what about `'%ann%ann%'` in the string `'Ann wore a bandanna' `  so you could change to white space such as `'% ann % ann %'` but then what about the `'Ann, Mike, and I where playing and Ann won'`  but it is a fast and dirty way without splitting the string on white space and removing punctuation such as commas etc.

Comment: @Matt You're right. That is the common issue with LIKE queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this,

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE post_content LIKE '%mike%mike%'
```

i tested it out in MySQL, and it is working exactly as you want it to.

[image]